# Android layout flip/turn  showing errors in logcat

Tags: android, android-layout, flip

I am newbie to android. After a bit of search in google I tried an animation program and its  closing in the emulator forcefully and not showing any thing while running the project

I want to have a flip/turn effect  for two layouts(xml files) i.e for signin.xml and register.xml. With single click on  new-user button in signin.xml I want to turn the layout to register.xml

I have taken  two layouts and tried to implement, i.e Linear and table layouts. Is it  the right procedure what I followed

I have added single button for a trial, but its not working and I want to know whats the wrong  with this code

I am getting no errors but problem with emulator while running.

plz some one help me,...Thanks!

these r my xml files

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/Layout01"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:background="@drawable/loginapp">
 <Button  android:layout_width="49px"  android:layout_height="44px" android:background="@drawable/login_home_btn_over_green" android:id="@+id/widget38"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:gravity="center" android:layout_marginTop="25dip" android:layout_height="177dip" android:background="@drawable/login_form_bg_green" android:layout_width="296dip">
     <EditText android:layout_marginRight="0dip"  android:id="@+id/userNameBox" android:layout_width="200px" android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" android:maxLines="1" android:layout_marginLeft="85dip" android:inputType="text" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
     <EditText android:layout_marginRight="0dip"  android:id="@+id/passwordBox" android:layout_width="200px" android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" android:maxLines="1" android:layout_marginTop="45dip" android:layout_marginLeft="85dip" android:inputType="text|textVisiblePassword" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_three" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_below="@+id/ll_two" android:gravity="center">
      <Button 
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:text="New user"/>
 </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

register.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/Layout02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TableRow>
     <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView"   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" REGISTER:"/>    
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First Name:"/>
    <EditText android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
      android:id="@+id/userNameBox" android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:maxLines="1" android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"   android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="text" android:layout_height="35px" android:layout_width="0dip"></EditText>


    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Last Name:"/>
    <EditText android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
      android:id="@+id/userNameBox" android:layout_width="200px"  android:layout_weight="1" 
      android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" android:maxLines="1"
       android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:inputType="text" 
       android:layout_height="35px"></EditText>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Email:"/>
    <EditText 
     android:id="@+id/userNameBox" android:layout_width="200px"
      android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"  android:layout_weight="1"
       android:maxLines="1" android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginRight="0dip"  
       android:inputType="text" android:layout_height="35px">
       </EditText>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
     <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mobile No:"/>
    <EditText android:layout_marginRight="0dip" 
     android:id="@+id/userNameBox" android:layout_width="200px"   android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
       android:maxLines="1" android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:inputType="text" android:layout_height="35px">
        </EditText>

    </TableRow>

  <TableRow>
  <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Register"
        android:id="@+id/Button03"
          android:padding="3dip"
          android:layout_marginLeft="45dip"
          android:layout_marginRight="90dip"
          android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
          android:layout_column="1"

          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_weight="1"/>
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

flip3d.java

```
package com.animation;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

public class Flip3d extends Activity {


private LinearLayout layout01;
private TableLayout layout02;

private boolean isFirstLayout = true;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Button newuser =(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);
layout01 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout01);
layout02 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout02);
layout02.setVisibility(View.GONE);

newuser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
    if (isFirstLayout) {       
     applyRotation(0, 90);
     isFirstLayout = !isFirstLayout;

    } else {    
     applyRotation(0, -90);
     isFirstLayout = !isFirstLayout;
    }
   }
});          
}

private void applyRotation(float start, float end) {
// Find the center of image
final float centerX = layout01.getWidth() / 2.0f;
final float centerY = layout01.getHeight() / 2.0f;

// Create a new 3D rotation with the supplied parameter
// The animation listener is used to trigger the next animation
final FlipAnimation rotation =
       new FlipAnimation(start, end, centerX, centerY);
rotation.setDuration(500);
rotation.setFillAfter(true);
rotation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
rotation.setAnimationListener(new DisplayNextView(isFirstLayout, layout01, layout02));

if (isFirstLayout)
{
layout01.startAnimation(rotation);
} else {
layout02.startAnimation(rotation);
}

}

public void setLayout01(LinearLayout layout01) {
    this.layout01 = layout01;
}

public LinearLayout getLayout01() {
    return layout01;
}

public void setLayout02(TableLayout layout02) {
    this.layout02 = layout02;
}

public TableLayout getLayout02() {
    return layout02;
}
}
```

Flipanimation.java

```
package com.animation;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;

public class FlipAnimation  extends Animation {
private final float mFromDegrees;
private final float mToDegrees;
private final float mCenterX;
private final float mCenterY;
private Camera mCamera;

public FlipAnimation(float fromDegrees, float toDegrees,
   float centerX, float centerY) {
mFromDegrees = fromDegrees;
mToDegrees = toDegrees;
mCenterX = centerX;
mCenterY = centerY;
}

@Override
public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
mCamera = new Camera();
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
final float fromDegrees = mFromDegrees;
float degrees = fromDegrees + ((mToDegrees - fromDegrees) * interpolatedTime);

final float centerX = mCenterX;
final float centerY = mCenterY;
final Camera camera = mCamera;

final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();

camera.save();

camera.rotateY(degrees);

camera.getMatrix(matrix);
camera.restore();

matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);

}

}
```

Displaynextview.java

```
package com.animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

public final class DisplayNextView implements Animation.AnimationListener {
private boolean mCurrentView;
LinearLayout layout01;
TableLayout layout02;

public DisplayNextView(boolean isFirstLayout, LinearLayout layout01,
        TableLayout layout02) {
    mCurrentView = isFirstLayout;
    this.layout01 = layout01;
    this.layout02 = layout02;

}

public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
}

public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
layout01.post(new SwapViews(mCurrentView, layout01, layout02));
}

public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
}
```

swapview.java

```
package com.animation;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

public final class SwapViews implements Runnable {
private boolean mIsFirstView;
LinearLayout layout01;
TableLayout layout02;

public SwapViews(boolean isFirstLayout, LinearLayout layout01, TableLayout layout02) {
 mIsFirstView = isFirstLayout;
 this.layout01 = layout01;
 this.layout02 = layout02;
}

public void run() {
 final float centerX = layout01.getWidth() / 2.0f;
 final float centerY = layout02.getHeight() / 2.0f;
 FlipAnimation rotation;

 if (mIsFirstView) {
  layout01.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  layout02.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  layout02.requestFocus();

     rotation = new FlipAnimation(-90, 0, centerX, centerY);
 } else {
  layout02.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  layout01.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  layout01.requestFocus();

     rotation = new FlipAnimation(90, 0, centerX, centerY);
 }

 rotation.setDuration(500);
 rotation.setFillAfter(true);
 rotation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

 if (mIsFirstView) {
  layout02.startAnimation(rotation);
 } else {
  layout01.startAnimation(rotation);
 }
}
}
```

flip.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<include android:id="@+id/notelist" layout="@layout/main" />
<include android:id="@+id/notelist" layout="@layout/register" />
</FrameLayout>
```

these r the errors in LOGCAT

04-26 12:48:27.877: INFO/ActivityManager(57): Start proc com.animation for activity com.animation/.Login: pid=294 uid=10047 gids={}
04-26 12:48:27.887: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(276): Shutting down VM
04-26 12:48:27.947: DEBUG/jdwp(276): adbd disconnected
04-26 12:48:27.988: INFO/AndroidRuntime(276): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
04-26 12:48:28.647: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(294): Shutting down VM
04-26 12:48:28.657: WARN/dalvikvm(294): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.animation/com.animation.Login}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.animation.Login in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.animation-1.apk]
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.animation.Login in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.animation-1.apk]
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
04-26 12:48:28.697: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     ... 11 more
04-26 12:48:28.757: WARN/ActivityManager(57):   Force finishing activity com.animation/.Login
04-26 12:48:29.267: WARN/ActivityManager(57): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{43fe6f90 com.animation/.Login}
04-26 12:48:39.376: WARN/ActivityManager(57): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{43fe6f90 com.animation/.Login}
04-26 12:48:44.548: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(57): pokeWakelock(5000)
04-26 12:48:44.658: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(57): pokeWakelock(5000)
04-26 12:48:44.888: WARN/WindowManager(57): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
04-26 12:48:44.958: INFO/ARMAssembler(57): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x360da0:0x360f68] in 5876460 ns
04-26 12:48:45.018: INFO/ARMAssembler(57): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [ 33 ipp] (47 ins) at [0x360f70:0x36102c] in 606224 ns
04-26 12:48:49.278: INFO/Process(294): Sending signal. PID: 294 SIG: 9
04-26 12:48:49.288: INFO/ActivityManager(57): Process com.animation (pid 294) has died.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code on emulator and its working now. You have to first change the included layout name in flip3d.java

```
setContentView(R.id.flip); //currenlty its R.id.main
```

Then you copy the actual layout contents of main.xml and register.xml into flip.xml itslef instead of including them using include tag. It seems emulator cant handle layout inclusion this way.